# Does J2ME supports Apache Lucene?

Tags: java, java-me

Is it possible to use apache lucene in J2ME application? If yes, then say me procedure?
can we use lucene's jar file in j2me application? how?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be Does Apache Lucene support J2ME, or is it just me? :-)

Comment: Right...Question should be such like

Answer (score 1):

Definitively not. Lucene is a framework conceived for JavaSE, and using JavaSE specific classes, as you can see in the class below, using ArrayList and Iterable, which don"t exist in JavaME:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.java?view=markup